# External HDD won't recognize

Tags: windows-7, usb

Good morning to all!

I bought a Lenovo x240 but the problem is that it wont recognize my 1TB WD External HDD only. I tried plugin my Externall HDD to different Laptop and PC but it seems ok. Can anyone help me on this? Please Please Please. Thank you all.

Comment: We need more information

Answer (score 1):

[Right click] My Computer > Manage
In System Tools, select Device Manager. Click the arrow to view all Serial Bus Controllers.
If any one of them is Disabled, it shall show a Yellow colored Warning. Right Click, Enable it and reboot, else Update the Drivers.

Answer (score -3):

You could try troubleshooting from the easiest steps first. You never know, the issue may be simpler to resolve than you think.

For instance, have you tried your external WD hard drive on only one USB port on your laptop? Try it on all of them, if it works, then one of your USB ports is dead.

If it doesn't work, then it's not that simple of a solution. Since your drive is active on other PC's, looks like yours is having some kind of a driver problem with the HDD. This is basically what @Technolust has already explained.

By looking under Disk drives in Device Manager, you can determine whether you have a driver problem - if there is a yellow exclamation mark next to the certain device. In Properties you can also look at the error message. You may have to update the drivers like already mentioned. You could choose the Uinstall option when clicking on the device. Then restart and hopefully Windows will reinstall the driver and configure it correctly when you reconnect the external hard drive.